# How to keep Android SDK up to date in a team development environment?

Tags: android, sdk

I work in a team of developers who are all using Android.

Each of us manually updates our SDK through the Android SDK Manager.

To me this seems like overkill. We're each updating the SDK by downloading updates to our own local machines.

Is there a better way to do this? There was talk of storing the most up to date version on a local server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android update sdk --no-ui -s --filter platform,tool,platform-tool
```

you can execute a command like this one each time you boot your machine; the `android` command has several other options, feel free to run `android --help` to see all the available options.